# automatically change the gnome-terminal "title" for the window

Tags: gnome

Trying to change the title of a current gnome-terminal (similar to the "set title" that you can do manually")

The system is running Fedora 9. The HowTo Xterm-Title discusses how to set the prompt, for an xterm. Tried to implement the escape sequences with no luck. (might be something weird..)

Tried to use the gconftool to dump/change/load the changed conf attributes, and again, no luck. Also, set the PROMPT_COMMAND just in case the prompt command was somehow changing the title back (which is highly doubtful)

Searching the 'net indicates that a few people have tried to solve this with no luck...

I'd also like to figure out how to create a new gnome-terminal with a unique specified title...

once this is solved, i'l gladly create a quick writeup/post onn how to accomplish this for others...

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at your /etc/bashrc (or equivalent). Modern Linux distributions have this already in place - you just may have to enable it.

For instance,  on openSuSE, it's handled by a bash function:

```
ppwd () 
{ 
    local _t="$1" _w _x _u="$USER" _h="$HOST";
    test -n "$_t" || return;
    test "${_t#tty}" = $_t && _t=pts/$_t;
    test -O /dev/$_t || return;
    _w="$(dirs +0)";
    _x=$((${#_w}-18));
    test ${#_w} -le 18 || _w="...${_w#$(printf "%.*s" $_x "$_w")}";
    printf "\e]2;%s@%s:%s\007\e]1;%s\007" "$_u" "$_h" "$_w" "$_h" > /dev/$_t
}
```

and my PS1 is:

```
$(ppwd \l)\u@\h:\w>
```

This causes my xterm & gnome-terminal title to be set to user@host:/smartpath every time the prompt is displayed.

If you're read this far, you should know that the easy way to set the title one time is:

```
echo -e '\e]2;Title Text\007\e]1;\007'
```

Answer (score 4):

To change the title of the current window :

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -N "MyWindowTitle"
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the title changing working in a script with the help of `xtitle`. When returning from the script, the `gnome-terminal` prompt changes the title back to what it was.

Here's the command line for changing the prompt (and the title):

```
PS1="\[\e]0;NewTitleHere\a\]\u@\h:\w\$ "
```

and here's the script I use:

```
#!/bin/bash
xtitle ServerName
ssh user@server.doma.in
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on MikeyB's answer above, I created this brief csh script, `title` to change the title:

```
#!/bin/csh
echo -n "\e]2;$1\007\e]1;\007"
```

This can be invoked as: `./title "My New Title"`

Answer (score 1):

```
gnome-terminal --title="My New Terminal" &
```

Can launch into an infinite spawning of terminal processes which will take your machine down. Remove that users post.

**Try this instead**

```
printf '\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007' #set Terminal title
```

Answer (score 0):

The xterm sequences work fine for gnome-terminal.  What shell are you using and what did you put in your shell config file?

Answer (score 0):

To create a new gnome-terminal with a unique specified title, you can specify the title on the command line:

```
gnome-terminal --title="My New Terminal" &
```

Answer (score 0):

Argh, so many answers...

I tried wmctrl, which *almost* worked, except I couldnt get it to change the icon title, at least not permanently.

The solution is that PS1 in ubuntu sets the title.

The default PS1 is

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

... which sets the title in the first escape sequence.

Thus, there are two solutions:

**Solution 1: simplify PS1, then use PROMPT_COMMAND**

Change PS1 to something simpler:

```
PS1="\u@\h:\w\$ "
```

... then use the PROMPT_COMMAND:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007"'
```

**Solution 2: directly modify PS1**

Simply modify PS1 with new title:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;newtitle\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```